# Can't See Data In pgAdmin after using python code

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, pgadmin

I am trying to take a dataframe and import it into a postgresql database. I've done this before and can always see the data in the database using pgAdmin. However, this time, there's no data visable in pgAdmin.

This is the SQL code I've used to create my table in the postgresql database:

```
CREATE TABLE Twitterapp
(
    tweetid character varying(255),
    tweettext character varying(255),
    tweetretweetct integer,
    tweetfavoritect integer,
    tweetsource character varying(255),
    tweetcreated character varying(255),
    userid character varying(255),
    userscreen character varying(255),
    username character varying(255),
    usercreatedt character varying(255),
    user_desc character varying(255),
    userfollowerct integer,
    userfriendsct integer,
    userlocation character varying(255),
    usertimezone character varying(255)

)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Then, using the sqlalchemy library in python, I tried to push my dataframe to the database:

```
#First attempt to load data 
engine =create_engine('postgresql://username:password@link:5432/db_name')
conn = engine.connect()    
a.to_sql('public.twitterapp', con=conn, if_exists='replace', 
index=False)
```

Since that operation was successful, I try to read a table from the database to check sure it worked:

```
##call data from database
result_set = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM twitterapp")  
for r in result_set:  
    print(r)
```

This code successfully returns the data in my dataframe but I still can't see it in my pgAdmin database. So I tried this second approach:

```
b = a.values.tolist()
sql2 = """INSERT INTO twitterapp VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"""
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_name' user='username' host='link' password='password'")
c = conn.cursor()
for row in b:
    c.execute(sql2, row)
    print(row)
conn.commit()
```

Again, it successfully executes (ie, doesn't throw an error) but no data shows in pgAdmin.

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

If you can show data during the session but not from pgAdmin (a different session) it's sure that your mistake is a wrong commit.
I'm not an expert of sqlalchemy but I think you have to read how to manage the session and how to commit it.
This is a good link:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html

You have to create a session object and execute a commit command:

```
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the port in psql if it's right or not. In my case local postgresql was listening to port 5433